# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - error after publishing

Tags: asp.net

I have a small function to retrieve a url. All of my user controls are inherited from this class, and were working well until I published my project. Then, the functions began returning "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is the main user control class:

```
 public class SeyyahWebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected string BaseURL
        {
            get
           {
            try
            {

                return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileServer"].ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                // This is for design time
                return null;
            }
          }
        }
}
```

I am using this inside the user controls source part, like so:

```
  <a href="<%= BaseURL%>/search.aspx" id="googlefancy">ara</a>
```

Normally, this is no problem. But when I publish ,<%= BaseURL %> starts to give

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I hope, I have explained my problem in good English :)
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is `VirtualFolder`, and what's its value?

Comment: i guess it doesnt matter,i just put an example.Im chaning it to a more simple code.

Comment: is your config file contains fileserver where ever you are publishing?

Comment: `catch { return null; }` is a terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this instead:

```
<a href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/search.aspx")%>' id="googlefancy">ara</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileServer"].ToString() == null ? "NOTHING" :  ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileServer"].ToString();
```

try this and debug to see what it returns.